# Dynamically change java script and css files of different modules in an application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.net MVC 5 application i currently have three modules and each module have it's own script files and style sheet files and there are some common scripts and style sheet files also, these are available to all the modules and even to entire application.

Currently i have one main div and i replace the entire html of that div with the opening module using jquery ajax and it's working fine, but in this way my modules state is not persistent means after opening second module if i open previously opened module it will be opened from it's initial state.

Now i want to persistent the state of each opened module. One approach in my mind is that i make three different empty div and replace the html of each respective module to it's own div and if any module's div is not empty then i just show that div and hide the remaining divs but in this way i think scripts and css files references of individual modules will not be removed when another module in opened.

Kindly please guide me how can i achieve that only currently opened module scripts and css files are referenced in the page and remaining files references are removed along with my html of each module is persistent.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: RequireJS is an option if you want to load script files that are required for a particular module only.

Comment: Yes! RequireJs will be better approch :)

Comment: And what about css files? ABHILASH SB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the solution and it's working fine....

1. First of all i have created three empty divs in my main view and on opening any module i send the ajax call to controller to bring the html of the partial view of opening module and this html in the respective empty div....
2. I have created one more div in all the three modules with class same class (eg. "scripts-styles-section" and i have placed all the scripts and styles of each module in the respective div of each module....
3. When my module is opening first time read the html of opening module "scripts-styles-section" div and store in the variable located in the common script file (which is available to all the modules and entire application....
4. When any other module is opening i clear the html of "scripts-styles-section" div in previously opened module....
5. Point 3 is performed again to newly opening module.
6. When previously opened module is opening again then i place the scripts and style stored in the variable to the "scripts-styles-section" div of it. and point 4 is performed to currently opened module.

Answer (score 0):

you can make three views for your three modules with their corresponding `css` and `scripts` files now `render` those view in your `main div`, this way you can render your view in you `main div`. you can add `common` `css` and `scripts` in `main div` file.

Comment: currently i am doing the same thing... but now i have to retain the html of my each modules, so their states can be persistent but i just have to keep the references of scripts and css of currently opened module.

Comment: your `modules views` are keeping the `html`